# Default Values for Models in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model, default-value

Is it possible to set default values for models ? For example consider this model from Appengine Documentation

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Pet(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    type = db.StringProperty(required=True, choices=set(["cat", "dog", "bird"]))
    birthdate = db.DateProperty()
    weight_in_pounds = db.IntegerProperty()
    spayed_or_neutered = db.BooleanProperty()
    owner = db.UserProperty(required=True)
```

I want to set the default value of `name` to be "Unnamed Pet", so if the user doesn't supply it , The default values taken . So is this possible ?

PS : I want this to be done in the model class `Pet` itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the default attribute, e.g.

```
class Pet(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True, default="(unnamed)")
```

Comment: Thanks I have been trying to find this in the documentation for sometime now

Comment: I was about to post a link to the docs, and then I discover that its not (well) document. Nick please do something about it :)

Comment: BTW: I don't know if it works with the required attribute, you might have to pass value in the ctor to name field even though it has a has a default value, which pretty much make the default attribute in this case useless.

Comment: This is documented in the [Property class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property)

Comment: @JesseRusak Yes but not in the db.Model where a lot of people are using as reference

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Because it's not part of `db.Model`.

Comment: @NickJohnson I meant [this page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html) which a lot of people use as reference, some attributes are documented there but not "default" (a least not for most of the properties). I know that its already documented in the Property class and that "repeating myself sucks" but IMHO the documentation should mention the other properties on that page as well.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen That page only documents the arguments unique to each property class. It links to the documentation on `Property`, which describes the arguments common to all of them.